# Odd cohomology of fibre bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Suppose that $B$ and $F$ are connected,  simply connected, compact, finite dimensional CW complexes. Assume additionally that both are Poicare duality spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose further  that for any odd integer $i$ we have $H^{i}(B,\mathbb{Z}) = H^{i}(F,\mathbb{Z})= 0$.

Let $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a (connected) fibre bundle with fibre $F$.

**Question:** Is it true that $H^{i}(E,\mathbb{Z})= 0$, for any odd integer $i$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but why is odd important? What happens in the even case?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can think of 2 reasons I restrict to the odd case. Firstly under my assumptions, the degree 0 cohomology (of $B$ or $F$) can never vanish. Secondly I am interested in computing in some specific example that have no odd cohommolgy, and it would be very nice if this statement was true.

Comment: By the way, "orientable" does not have any meaning in this context, and any compact CW complex is automatically finite-dimensional (in fact, finite).

Comment: Thanks, I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  First, note that $B$ must have even dimension (as a Poincare duality space) and therefore by Poincare duality its homology is also trivial in odd degrees.  It then follows by the universal coefficient theorem that the homology groups of $B$ are free (otherwise the torsion would show up as odd-degree cohomology), and so the odd degree cohomology of $B$ vanishes for any choice of coefficients.

Now the conclusion follows immediately from the Serre spectral sequence.  There is a spectral sequence whose $E_2$ page is $H^p(B,H^q(F,\mathbb{Z}))$ which converges to $H^{p+q}(E,\mathbb{Z})$.  For $H^p(B,H^q(F,\mathbb{Z}))$ to be nonzero, $p$ and $q$ must both be even, in which case $p+q$ is even as well, and so $H^i(E,\mathbb{Z})$ can only be nonzero if $i$ is even.  (In fact, more strongly, we can see that all the differentials of the spectral sequence will have either trivial domain or trivial codomain, and so the spectral sequence collapses at $E_2$).